# SQL Server tempDB data file is growing very fast. 120gb

Tags: sql-server-2014, tempdb

My tempDB is now over 120GB. It has grown 65GB in a couple of hours. It is not the log but the actual DB that is growing. Reports show 99% is unused space. I tried restarting the server that SQL Server is on in hopes that would clear it out but the size did not reduce. How do I fix this? I can't seem to get it to release the allocated space.

UPDATE: I have manged to gain back 1 gb from Temp db. The c: drive now has 21gb of free space and the tempDB is not growing now. Our offices are closed and I am the only working.

Comment: Are you loading any data? check activity monitor for long running queries

Comment: I did check for long running queries both before and after I restarted sql server and there were none. I was hoping that was the issue but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Run sp_whoisactive or similar script and see what is running on your db, check for any sql jobs, google for a query to see what is using up tempdb space, review that an update your question with more information.